# why does ggplot plot lines differently when colors are factor vs numeric

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm getting better at making ggplots, but can't figure out why lines get plotted differently when colors are based on continuous numbers vs discrete factors.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Blues')+
  labs(title='Discrete, class(Species) = factor')
```

The plot above connects all the setosa points together. The plot below draws vertical lines connecting setosa points with other species points. Why?

```
iris$SpeciesNum=as.numeric(iris$Species)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=SpeciesNum)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_distiller(palette='Blues')+
  labs(title='Continuous, class(SpeciesNum) = numeric')
```

In my real case, there's over 50 color values and while there's no need for the viewer to distinguish color #1 from color #2, I'd like to use the continuous color option to get a nice gradient but have the points connected to one another in the way that the discrete plot does it. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know your data, but in general the behaviour for `geom_line()` will be fixed when you call a `group` within the `aes()`. Eg. `ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=SpeciesNum, group = SpeciesNum)) + ...`

Comment: Because factors are discrete and numbers are continuous. Without `group`, like @Stephan says, the discrete colors will map to different lines, the continuous ones will map one line to a continuous scale.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Stephan, that did it!

Desired behavior:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, group=Species, color=SpeciesNum)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_distiller(palette='Blues')+
  labs(title='group=Species, color=SpeciesNum, class(SpeciesNum) = numeric')
```

Comment: Please ask @Stephan if he can put that up as an answer so you can accept (and we all can upvote) the answer so that his reputation score can increase.